# Flatten nested list and retain all parent keys for each bottom-level element

Tags: r, recursion, nested-lists, flatten

I need to flatten an **arbitrarily** nested list to a data frame and retain the path of keys / indices in one column, while extracting each element on the bottom level to an individual row.

Consider the following list:

```
lst <- list(
    animals = list(
        lamas = c("brown", "white"),
        primates = list(
            humans = c("asia", "europe"),
            apes = c("good", "fast", "angry")
        )
    ),
    objects = c("expensive", "cheap"),
    plants = NULL
)
```

The results of `flatten_list(lst, delimiter="_")` should look like this:

```
data.frame(
  path = c("animals_lamas", "animals_lamas", "animals_primates_humans", "animals_primates_humans", "animals_primates_apes", "animals_primates_apes", "animals_primates_apes", "objects", "objects", "plants"),
  value = c("brown", "white", "asia", "europe", "good", "fast", "angry", "expensive", "cheap", NA)
)
```

I was surprised that I couldn't achieve this with tidyr or data.tables. Do I need a recursive function, or is there some out-of-the-box solution for this? Appreciated!

**EDIT:** The solution provided by [akrun](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3732271/akrun) worked on the original data. I realized that there is a problem when an element is `NULL` at the bottom level and hence rephrased the problem.

**EDIT2** My current workaround is to recursively replace `NULL` by `NA` before applying [akrun](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3732271/akrun) solution, using the function [supplied here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61417461/1114975) [again by akrun ;) ].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can be done by `melt`ing into a data.frame and then `unite` the key columns

```
library(reshape2)
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
out2 <- melt(lst) %>% 
        unite(path, L1:L3, sep = "_", na.rm = TRUE) %>% 
        select(path, value)
```

-checking with OP's output

```
> all.equal(out, out2)
[1] TRUE
```

---

We may also do this with `unlist` and `stack` from `base R`

```
stack(unlist(lapply(lst, \(x) if(is.null(x)) NA_character_ else x)))[2:1]
```

Comment: Thank you, that solves the problem with the test data. I just realized that I've tried this solution before, but it doesn't work with my actual data, since some elements at the bottom level are `NULL`. Hope you don't mind if I rephrase the problem

Comment: @ComfortEagle i see your edit stating that you were able to fix it

Answer (score 2):

A solution that can deal with `NULL`, based on `rrapply`:

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(rrapply)

rrapply(lst, f = \(x) if (is.null(x)) NA else x, how = "melt") %>% 
  unnest(value) %>% unite(path, L1:L3, na.rm = T)

#> # A tibble: 10 × 2
#>    path                    value    
#>    <chr>                   <chr>    
#>  1 animals_lamas           brown    
#>  2 animals_lamas           white    
#>  3 animals_primates_humans asia     
#>  4 animals_primates_humans europe   
#>  5 animals_primates_apes   good     
#>  6 animals_primates_apes   fast     
#>  7 animals_primates_apes   angry    
#>  8 objects                 expensive
#>  9 objects                 cheap    
#> 10 plants                  <NA>
```